# Different return values for multiple calls in NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I mocked an iterator and set it up to return multiple values. The first call it should return true, the second false.

I used this as a reference: https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/multiple-returns/

```
var iterator = Substitute.For<FeedIterator<Product>>();
iterator.HasMoreResults.Returns(true, false);
```

But when I run the test the return value is always false. If I switch the parameters return value is always true.

It looks like this sequence is not working, or am I missing something?

As requested the test:

```
[Fact]
public async void GetAll_ReturnsProducts()
{
    //arrange
    var product = new Product();
    var container = Substitute.For<Container>();
    var cosmosLinqQuery = Substitute.For<ICosmosLinqQuery>();
    var iterator = Substitute.For<FeedIterator<Product>>();
    var feedResponse = Substitute.For<FeedResponse<Product>>();
    //var enumerator = Substitute.For<IEnumerator<Product>>();

    cosmosLinqQuery.GetFeedIterator<Product>(default).ReturnsForAnyArgs(iterator);
    container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Product>().Returns(new List<Product>().AsQueryable());
    IProductRepository productRepository = new ProductRepository(container, cosmosLinqQuery);            
    iterator.HasMoreResults.Returns(false, false, true);

    //feedResponse.GetEnumerator().Returns(enumerator);
    iterator.ReadNextAsync().Returns(feedResponse);

    //act
    var products = await productRepository.GetAll();

    //assert
    Assert.Same(product, products.First());
}
```

And the method that is tested:

```
async Task<IList<Product>> IProductRepository.GetAll()
{
    var query = (from p in container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Product>()
                    select p);
    var iterator = cosmosLinqQuery.GetFeedIterator(query);

    var products = new List<Product>();

    while(iterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        foreach(var item in await iterator.ReadNextAsync())
        {
            products.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return products;
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything obvious from the posted snippet. Can you please post the test as well?

Comment: I updated the question with the complete code

Comment: _But when I run the test the return value is always false. If I switch the parameters return value is always true._ - how you check those values?